# Cannot unmarshal float32 value into string

Tags: json, floating-point, go, marshalling

I have a JSON response that returns a UNIX timestamp value for the `created` field:

```
"created_utc": 1395800038.0

---

// The type I use to marshal the response JSON.
// I can't use string because Golang complains the JSON is a float.
type Submission struct {
    CreatedUtc          float32         `json:"created_utc"`
}
```

I want to convert this to an actual `Time` object:

```
const longForm = "Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)"
created_at, _ := time.Parse(longForm, string(created_utc))
```

> ./main.go:57: cannot convert created_utc (type float32) to type string

---

So I'm sort of stuck here. Either I can force the marshal code to convert the timestamp to a string, or I can convert the float value to a string on the `time.Parse` code - but I can't seem to do either without Golang complaining.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

**Using float32 for a Unix timestamp**

As Nick Craig-Wood already pointed out, a float32 cannot store a Unix timestamp without loss of precision. And while the JSON standard doesn't restrict the precision of a number, Javascript restricts them to IEEE 754 64-bit floating point values.

That being said, it is a good practice to store JSON numbers in float64 variables to avoid loosing precision, unless you are certain the number fits well in an int (no decimals) or float32, or whatever.

**Converting float64 to string to get Time?**

Converting float to string sounds like:

> 1395800038.0 => "1395800038.0"

I will assume that is not your intent, but rather that wish to get one of the following:

1. `var t time.Time = time.Unix(1395800038, 0)`
2. `var s string = "Mar 26, 2014 at 2:13am (UTC)" // Or any other format`

And even if your aim is to get to the string (2), you still would need to create the time.Time variable (1). So it will happen in two steps.

**Solution:**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var data = []byte(`{"created_utc": 1395800038.0}`)

type Submission struct {
    CreatedUtc float64 `json:"created_utc"`
}

func main() {
    var sub Submission
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &sub)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // First step, convert float64 to a time.Time (after a quick conversion to int64 as well)
    dt := time.Unix(int64(sub.CreatedUtc), 0)

    // Second step, convert the timestamp to a string representation of your choice
    fmt.Println(dt.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
}
```

**Result:**

```
2014-03-26 02:13:58
```

**Playground:** http://play.golang.org/p/jNwzwc4dLg

Answer (score 2):

You should use int64 to store the UNIX time (float doesn't make sense).

Then use this to convert it to a `time.Time` instance:

```
var x int64 = 1398621956

dt := time.Unix(x, 0) // setting nsec to 0
created_at := dt.Format("Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)")

fmt.Println(created_at)
```

If you really have to use float use `float64` (this will prevent the parsing issue) and use this to convert to `int64`:

```
var y float64 = 1398621956.0
x := int64(y)
```

Comment: Yep, that makes sense however: `json: cannot unmarshal number 1343520356.0 into Go value of type int64` - So I'm back to square one you see. :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't store a unix timestamp in a float32 it doesn't fit!

A float32 has only 24 bits of mantissa - whereas a current unix time needs 31 bits.

So if you do store a unix time in a float32 you'll get reduced precision, eg

```
func main() {
    t := 1395800038.0
    v := float32(t)
    dv := float64(v) - t
    fmt.Printf("v = %f, difference is %f\n", v, dv)
}
```

Which prints

```
v = 1395800064.000000, difference is 26.000000
```

([Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/5fCYZ5jJr9))

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your other question's answer [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23318188/145587)....

Anyway, that's a unix timestamp (in javascript `+(new Date())`), you can use [`time.Unix`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix) to convert it to `time.Time` :

[Play link](http://play.golang.org/p/Z74Dm2LcNq)

```
func main() {
    t := 1395800038.0
    fmt.Println(time.Unix(int64(t), 0))
}
//output : 2014-03-26 02:13:58 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: My question is about specifically converting a float64 to a string.

Comment: that float is a timestamp, you can't convert it to a string like that... now you use `time.Unix(int64(t), 0).Format("Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)")` or you can change how you store it in json or use `strconv.ParseFloat`.